# How to plot multiple rarefaction data in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have data something looks like this:

```
    Sample1       Sample 2     Sample 3       Sample 4
Reads    OTUs   Reads OTUs   Reads   OTUs   Reads   OTUs
100       26    90     17     80      47     95      43
500       35    250    23     290     52     315     59
700       40    490    29     350     60     460     62
```

I need to plot `Reads` on the X-axis and `OTUs` on the Y-axis, with all samples with different colors. Any idea how can I plot this in R or in any other software?

Answer (score 1):

A `ggplot2` solution:

```
# reading the data
data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Reads.Sample1    OTUs.Sample1   Reads.Sample2 OTUs.Sample2   Reads.Sample3   OTUs.Sample3   Reads.Sample4   OTUs.Sample4
100       26    90     17     80      47     95      43
500       35    250    23     290     52     315     59
700       40    490    29     350     60     460     62")

# reshaping the data into long format
require(reshape2)
melted <- cbind(
  melt(data, measure=c("Reads.Sample1","Reads.Sample2","Reads.Sample3","Reads.Sample4"),
       variable.name="Reads", value.name="rvalue"),
  melt(data, measure=c("OTUs.Sample1","OTUs.Sample2","OTUs.Sample3","OTUs.Sample4"),
       variable.name="OTUs", value.name="ovalue"))
melted <- melted[,c(5,6,11,12)]

# creating the plot
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(melted, aes(x=rvalue, y=ovalue, color=Reads)) +
  geom_point(shape=20, size=4) +
  scale_color_discrete("Sample", breaks=c("Reads.Sample1","Reads.Sample2","Reads.Sample3","Reads.Sample4"), 
                    labels=c(" 1"," 2"," 3"," 4")) +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
DF <- read.table(text="    Sample1       Sample 2     Sample 3       Sample 4
Reads    OTUs   Reads OTUs   Reads   OTUs   Reads   OTUs
100       26    90     17     80      47     95      43
500       35    250    23     290     52     315     59
700       40    490    29     350     60     460     62", skip=1, header=TRUE)

matplot(DF[, seq(1, ncol(DF), by=2)], DF[, seq(2, ncol(DF), by=2)], pch=16)
legend("topright", legend=seq_len(ncol(DF)/2), col=seq_len(ncol(DF)/2), pch=16)
```